# Logging suite with back-end for PHP?

Tags: php, logging

Does anybody know an all-purpose logging suite for PHP applications?

By "suite" I mean a lightweight library of logging functions **as well as a mature back-end to view them.**

The back-end would have to be configurable and show log entries using functions like

- Filter by date
- Filter by event (Warning, error, custom event)
- Filter by category
- Filter by user
- Filter by associated database record (optional, I could add that myself)

I would like to use such an engine as a "log book" for database records inside my app - e.g. as a diary for a vehicle record, detailing events like "phone call", "buyer interest", "accident", "repair", "theft/damage"....)

The possibility to export log events through the PHP library (to show an event log within the app) is mandatory. RSS / XML export would also be nice.

I'm doing this myself at the moment inside the application. I've never seen anything like this so I realize it's a long shot, but I'm curious to seewhether there is any third party solution to this very common task.

Comment: Not a real answer, but the most simple thing that could possibly work is using syslog. There are a couple of tools, GUI and web for viewing the stuff. However, syslog is a linear textual log format, so no cool features and extensions had to be shoehorned into its text line format (csv/json?). http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/syslogweb.htm

Answer (score 2):

See if [Apache's log4php](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/) suits your needs:

> Log4php is logging framework for PHP
>   at the Apache Software Foundation
>   (ASF), sponsored by the Apache Logging
>   Services project.
>
> Log4PHP has completed graduation in
>   March 2010.
>
> log4php supports:
>
> - Configuration through xml and properties file (same structure as
>     log4j).
> - File, RollingFile, DailyFile, Echo, Console, Mail, PDO, PHP error,
>     Syslog or NT events and Socket
>     appenders.
> - Simple, TTCC, Pattern, Html and Xml Layouts.
> - Nested (NDC) and Mapped (MDC) Diagnostic Contexts.

Comment: Looks interesting, I will take a look.