# Designing Log system

Tags: php, mysql, html, logging

I am designing a online website (PHP, HTML and MySQL) with one of the functionalities being able to upload and download the records to/from database. I want to keep a log of all the records that were successfully added to the database and all the failed ones as well. If I wish to save this log file on the local machine, how should I go about with designing the log system ? i.e.

1. location of the log file and being compatible with various O.S
2. General format that can provide as much information as possible i.e SQL error
3. Any other pointers I need to consider.

---

Can anyone please guide me to the correct setup?

I have included `include '/Logger.php';` line in my php file. However, I want to write the log to a file and I don't understand if the configuration file is `log4php.xml` or `appender_file.properties`. Can anyone please tell me the setup to log write to a file/?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388978/logging-suite-with-back-end-for-php (but has the same answer as this one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[log4php](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/) is a library that meets all these objectives. It can write logs to:

1. File OR
2. Syslog (Unix) OR
3. System Events (Windows)

And is configured via XML. All standard logging functions like log file rotation (E.g. create a new log file after size is 10 MB or every day, zip previous files) and customizable layout of files.